# How to populate a drop down list value into a text box for an ssrs report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have an SSRS report . I use a  parameter as a dropdownlist and I have populated the dropdownlist with a dataset.

The query in the dataset is as follows

```
 select Id, Name from Product;
```

I use `Id` for the Value and Name for the `Label` in the dropdownlist.

I also have a text box on the report. I would like to populate the text box with the label of the dropdownlist.

So as soon as the dropdownlist is changed and view report is pressed , the textbox value needs to be updated to the dropdownlist value. Does anyone know how it can be done ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To display a parameter value in a textbox in a report, use an expression like:

```
=Parameters!MyParameter.Label
```

Where `MyParameter` is the name of your parameter.

For a multi-valued parameter, use:

```
=Join(Parameters!MyParameter.Label, ", ")
```

Here you are using the `Join` function to turn the array of selected value labels into a string to display.

See [Parameters Collection References](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255264.aspx) for some more examples.

Comment: the thing is , I am using Id as the value , but I would like the Name in the textbox.

Comment: Did you have any luck with this after the update to the answer?